# jpGraph plot lines with negative values putting ticks at 0

Tags: jpgraph

I'm using jpGraph to plot items on a line graph. The values extend from -20 to +20, but when I output the graph, the X-axis labels start at 0, so they're right in the middle of the graph, instead of at the bottom:

[image: Sample graph with tick labels in the middle]

Here's the code that replicates the issue:

```
<?php
    // Using the Composer version: https://packagist.org/packages/jpgraph/jpgraph
    require("vendor/autoload.php");

    \JpGraph\JpGraph::load();
    \JpGraph\JpGraph::module('line');

    $graph = new \Graph(640, 480);
    $graph->SetScale("textint", -20, 20);

    $magValues = [-20, -10, 0, 10, 20];

    $lplotMag = new LinePlot($magValues);
    $graph->Add($lplotMag);

    $graph->Stroke();

?>
```

How can I force the X-axis labels to be at the bottom of the graph?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add this property

$graph->xaxis->SetPos("min");